# How to make qextserialport read bytes faster in Qt?

Tags: qt4

HI guys, I am using qextserialport for serial communication in Qt.
What happens is, when I send data from my controller board it reads the data,but it continues to read the data even though i turn off the board. 
That means it reads very slowly and when I turn off the board still bytes are remaining to be read on the terminal.so how to solve this problem??

when turn off the board it should stop reading the bytes.

Comment: chances are that you are missing some tuning on the values for the serial port on your board,  especially the clock/bps value. You need to inform yourself about how to manage the metric on a serial port.

Answer (score 0):

**The parity check in your serial port is misconfigured**.

- If you have already tried another serial terminal software and this works properly,
    Then you have misconfigured your driver qextserialport.

*you should follow this type of initialization:*

```
  ...

  bool uart_openPort(QString name, PortSettings *setting) {

        static bool port_created = false;

        if (port_created == false) {
            port = new QextSerialPort();
            port->setQueryMode(QextSerialPort::Polling);
            port_created = true;
        }

        if (connection_ready) {
            uart_closePort();
            connection_ready = false;
        }

        port->setPortName(name);
        port->setBaudRate (setting->BaudRate);
        port->setDataBits(setting->DataBits);
        port->setStopBits(setting->StopBits);
        port->setParity(setting->Parity);
        port->setFlowControl(setting->FlowControl);
        port->setTimeout(1);

        if (port->open(QextSerialPort::ReadWrite)) {
            connection_ready = true;
            qDebug("INFORMATION (UART OPEN PORT): Port open Successful!");

        } else {
            connection_ready = false;
            qDebug("CRITICAL (UART OPEN PORT): Error open Port!");
        }

        return(connection_ready);
    }

    ...
```

*or you could spend some fixed parameters in this mode*

```
...

    port->setPortName("/dev/ttyUSB0");
    port->setBaudRate(BAUD9600);
    port->setDataBits(DATA_8);
    port->setStopBits(STOP_1);
    port->setParity(PAR_NONE);
    port->setFlowControl(FLOW_OFF);
    port->setTimeout(1);

...
```

- If you do not get the proper functioning in any software,
  you should check your control parity settings on your board;
- If you are using an uart flow generated by software,
  in the serial sequence shall check that the proper placing the start bit and at the end of the transmission one byte is enough space for one stop bit.

Comment: /struct PortSettings {    BaudRateType BaudRate;DataBitsType DataBits;ParityType Parity;StopBitsType StopBits;FlowType FlowControl;ulong Timeout_Sec;ulong Timeout_Millisec;};
    PortSettings portSettings = { BAUD19200, DATA_8, PAR_NONE, STOP_1, FLOW_OFF, 0, 500};
    m_ptrSerialCommunicator = new SerialCommunicator("COM1", portSettings);
    if(!(m_ptrSerialCommunicator->OpenSerialPort("COM1",QIODevice::ReadWrite)))
    {
        exit(0);
    }

Comment: while(1)
    { if(m_ptrSerialCommunicator->IsSerialPortOpen())
        {   ui->StatusLabel->setText(tr("Serial port open."));
            if(m_ptrSerialCommunicator->IsDataAvailable(6,3000))
            {
                m_ptrSerialCommunicator->read(szTemp,6);
                count++;szTemp[6]='\0';
    
                Data = QString(szTemp).toDouble();
                plotdata = Data;
                emit Signal_For_Serial_Port(szTemp);
            }delay(10);//miliseconds
        }else
        { ui->StatusLabel->setText(tr("Serial port not open."));
        }
        Data=0;    }

Comment: This above code i am using to read 6 bytes each time,I am sending 6 bytes contineously from my controller board.

Comment: The problem is more elementary than I believed, **"while(1)" is BAD!**
you have a high-speed loop in the graphic thread. The rare break you did "delay(ms)", surely is not cooperative and certainly not a native method of QT, as is a QTimer->msleep or QThread::msleep, and this will have taken its processor load at 100%, you must use the serial port with a timer or a separate thread, also if you are capturing every byte at 19200 baud, a single byte, takes less than a ms to arrive, so your 500ms is excessive timeout.

Comment: So what do you suggest to do..?

Comment: how to use saperate thread?? the code for delay is as follows   void delay(int n)
{
    QTime dieTime= QTime::currentTime().addMSecs(n);
    while( QTime::currentTime() < dieTime )
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 100);
}

Comment: You must decide which is the best solution to suit your needs,
I personally use on Linux systems with a thread fed QextSP gives RTC interrupt.On win systems you should use a QTimer created within a separate thread, or you use the serial port event SIGNAL(readyRead ()), [QThread](http://sector.ynet.sk/qt4-tutorial/threads.html) [QTimer](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qtimer.html) [Event Example](http://docs.qextserialport.googlecode.com/git-history/3c714140fc7d5d85077626d8e22d8582ff105d2f/2.0/examples-uartassistant-dialog-cpp.html)